# Virtualbox 4.1.20 No Network Access from Guest on Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking

I cannot get the VirtualBox guest to connect to the host or vice-versa.  Whatever network setting I change on the guest does not seem to make any difference. I can see the internet and all the computers on my network from the host (Windows 7) wireless connection.  I cannot see anything from the guest (Windows XP).  Last week I was able to print from the guest, so the network connection must have worked because the printer is on the network.  I have tried for 3 hours now to get this connection to work.  I was trying to use the bridged connection so my guest has access to all the computers on the network and the internet.

Could someone please step me through the process of entering the settings on the guest and how to bridge on the host?

Answer (score 0):

Change the network settings of the guest to "Bridge" mode. You might have to restart the guest.

This will make your virtual machine just look like a normal machine to the rest of the network. You can print to a network printer, connect to file shares on other computers on the network, and access the internet

Answer (score 0):

1) change the network setting into like this :

[image: virtual box network settings]

2) Download and install driver from intel : You can get the driver from [this link](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18717/eng/PRO2K3XP_32.exe)

3) copy and then install the driver from your main OS using shared folder settings...

[image: virtual box sharing folders]

[image: windows xp sharing options]

As from picture above, choose your shared folder, then access the folder using this address from your Virtual Windows XP : "\vboxsrv\share" (without quote)

After installation complete, your network connection on virtual win xp should be something like this.

[image: windows xp network connections]

Comment: Thanks! I got an error message though: "Encodepointer was not found in dll-library KERNEL32.dll".